# Javassist - pass flags to compiler

Tags: java, reflection, javac, javassist

I've got quick question. I'm using *Javassist* to add methods to classes and then rebuild jar files.

*Javassist* using *Javac* to compiling code. But after compilation by *Javassist*, I cannot reach *LocalVariableTable* using e.g. *javap*.

I've read that flag *- g* must be set in compiler during the time of compilation.

Do you know how to force in *Javassist* to compile with self-defined flags, like *- g* ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.

*Javac* is internal compiler of *Javassist*. *Javac* class has method named *recordLocalVariables*.

*recordLocalVariables* is called 3 times in entire library (but it's also public method) in:

- *CtBehavior.insertBefore*
- *CtBehavior.insertAfter*
- *CtBehavior.insertAt*

To makes sure that local variables will be stored with bytecode, just use one of those methods during the creation of new method.